# Corrupted characters with an OLED displaying thermocouple output

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm super new to Arduinos but I'm learning as I go. I'm in the first stages of a small temperature control project and so far I've been able to display the output of a MAX31855 thermocouple breakout board on 124x64 spi OLED through my Arduino micro.

My problem is that the characters of the temperature are corrupted looking. As I think I understand it, the temperature is changing while it's being written to the display therefore you get overlapping values. I've attached an image of the display.[image]

I've tried making the temp output an integer but that didn't work.

Any input would be greatly appreciated as I'm just banging my head against the wall.

Here's my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MAX31855.h>
#include <U8glib.h>

//Constructor line for OLED

U8GLIB_SH1106_128X64 u8g(13, 11, 10, 9, 8);  // D0=13, D1=11, CS=10, DC=9, Reset=8

// Default connection is using software SPI, but comment and uncomment one of
// the two examples below to switch between software SPI and hardware SPI:

// Example creating a thermocouple instance with software SPI on any three
// digital IO pins.
#define MAXDO   3
#define MAXCS   4
#define MAXCLK  5

// initialize the Thermocouple
Adafruit_MAX31855 thermocouple(MAXCLK, MAXCS, MAXDO);

// Example creating a thermocouple instance with hardware SPI
// on a given CS pin.
//#define MAXCS   10
//Adafruit_MAX31855 thermocouple(MAXCS);



void draw() {
  double c = thermocouple.readCelsius();
  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_profont29);  // select font
  u8g.setPrintPos(5, 45);  // set position
  u8g.print(c);  // display temperature from MAX31855

}

void setup(void) {

}


void loop() {


  // picture loop
  u8g.firstPage();  
  do {

    draw();
  } while (u8g.nextPage());

  // rebuild the picture after some delay
  delay(5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The U8G2 library saves RAM by drawing the screen in smaller chunks (i.e., a "page").  Because you are taking a reading for each chunk, the temperature can change.  Just pull the reading out of `draw` and do it once in `loop`:

```
double c; // a global variable used in draw and loop

void draw() {
  u8g.setFont(u8g_font_profont29);  // select font
  u8g.setPrintPos(5, 45);  // set position
  u8g.print(c);  // display temperature from MAX31855

}

void loop() {

  c = thermocouple.readCelsius(); // set the global variable once

  // picture loop
  u8g.firstPage();  
  do {
    draw();
  } while (u8g.nextPage());

  // rebuild the picture after some delay
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: BOOM! Worked like a charm. Much appreciated.